# Fedora: Low disk on Filesystem root

Tags: linux, partition, virtualbox, disk-usage

I'm running a Fedora Workstation VM on Oracle VirtualBox. After using the VM for about a month now, I get a "Low disk on filesystem root" popup when I login. The Disk Usage Analyzer shows this:[image: Disk Usage]

I ran this to check for large files

```
find / -type f -exec ls -s {} \; | sort -n -r | head -20
```

And got these results:

```
[root@localhost ~]# find / -type f -exec ls -s {} \; | sort -n -r | head -20
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/proc/3355/task/3355/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/proc/3355/fdinfo/6': No such file or directory
1786352 /run/media/joe/Fedora-WS-Live-29-1-2/LiveOS/squashfs.img
210116 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
137672 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.ea.28-2.fc29.x86_64/lib/modules
119748 /usr/lib64/firefox/libxul.so
69396 /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-83995d8e04c4471c85be9b18e488ac62.img
59032 /usr/lib64/libLLVM-7.so
56264 /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb
49268 /var/cache/PackageKit/29/hawkey/fedora-filenames.solvx
49268 /var/cache/dnf/fedora-filenames.solvx
49257 /run/media/joe/Fedora-WS-Live-29-1-2/isolinux/initrd.img
49257 /run/media/joe/Fedora-WS-Live-29-1-2/images/pxeboot/initrd.img
47856 /var/cache/PackageKit/29/metadata/fedora-29-x86_64/repodata/55059fb25f8577d2a18d0883247b604dade9f3f68b5b54593ec1809acc57e5fc-filelists.xml.gz
47856 /var/cache/dnf/fedora-8c9e363c32277c01/repodata/55059fb25f8577d2a18d0883247b604dade9f3f68b5b54593ec1809acc57e5fc-filelists.xml.gz
46492 /usr/libexec/webkit2gtk-4.0/WebKitPluginProcess2
45380 /usr/lib64/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.33.3
43020 /var/lib/rpm/Packages
40072 /usr/lib64/libopenblas-r0.3.3.so
33576 /usr/lib64/firefox/browser/omni.ja
26224 /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.62.1
25276 /usr/share/fonts/google-noto-cjk/NotoSerifCJK-Bold.ttc
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please describe what sort of tasks this particular Fedora partition is intended to be used for.

Comment: I'm doing an online Linux System Admin course and using the VM to follow along with the videos. So things like practicing command line, editing config files, installing/removing packages, basic stuff.

Comment: Also, is it common for people to down vote without explaining why? Seems counter-productive.

Comment: It's an [anonymity thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_ballot).  See also: [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

Answer (score 0):

The (virtual) partition in question is *5.7* gigabytes, which is not that large for a working instance of Fedora.

The simplest thing would be to increase the size of the partition.

Comment: Increasing partition size isn't a great option for me, this is running on a laptop with limited space. I'm looking for a solution that cleans out unnecessary files.